# Бесконечный цикл while

Tags: c++, while, cin

я искренне не могу понять почему при выполнении такого цикла отладчик не заходит в реализацию
**std::cin** (cin тот, который в while). Пожалуйста, объясните почему так происходит.

```
int choiceMenu = 0;
std::cin >> choiceMenu;
while (choiceMenu < 1 || choiceMenu > 5 || std::cin.fail()) {
    std::cout << "Invalid choice, try again: ";
    std::cin >> choiceMenu;
}
```

Comment: Что вводите в первый раз?

Comment: 1) Не понятен смысл фразы `отладчик не заходит в реализацию std::cin`. На строке `std::cin >> choiceMenu;` жмёте «шаг с заходом», но заход внутрь не происходит? 2) В общем-то цикл организован неверно. Если выполнено условие `std::cin.fail()`, то поток находится в некорректном состоянии. Любые попытки ввода игнорируются. Необходимо сперва восстановить состояние потока (`std::cin.clear()`), затем очистить входной поток от оставшихся в нём некорректных символов (`std::cin.ignore(...)`), и только потом делать новую попытку считывания (`std::cin >> choiceMenu`).

Comment: @avp Пробую строку либо символ.

Comment: У меня (gdb) после ввода символа `a` заходит. Далее этот код бесконечно циклится...

Comment: Да, я хотел сказать что не заходит во внутренний cin именно, в общем я сделал как посоветовал @wololo, но подскажите, от чего зависит значение внутри cin.ignore? Это количество игнорируемых в дальнейшем символов?

Comment: Да, количество игнорируемых символов. Подробнее написал в ответе.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если при считывании целого числа во входном потоке находится последовательность символов, не представляющих число, или во входном потоке число, но оно вне диапазона представимых значений целевого типа, то входной поток устанавливает внутренний флаг ошибки [`failbit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate). Любые дальнейшие попытки ввода игнорируются.

Более того, если число не удалось считать, т.к. в потоке не число, то некорректная последовательность символов не будет извлечена из входного потока. Если просто сбросить флаг ошибки, то дальнейший ввод продолжится с некорректной последовательности символов.

Поэтому перед повторной попыткой считать число необходимо сбросить флаги ошибок с помощью функции [`clear()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear), а также очистить входной поток от некорректных символов.

Для очистки входного потока от некорректных символов можно использовать функцию [`ignore()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore):

```
basic_istream& ignore( std::streamsize count = 1, int_type delim = Traits::eof() );
```

Она извлекает из потока символы до тех пор, пока не извлечёт ровно `count` символов, либо пока не наткнётся на конец файла, либо пока не наткнётся на символ-разделитель `delim` (который также будет извлечён). Если параметр `count` равен максимальному значению, представимому целочисленным типом `std::streamsize`, то проверка количества извлечённых символов на равенство параметру `count` не производится.

Примерно так:

```
#include <limits>
...

auto delim = decltype(std::cin)::traits_type::to_int_type('\n');

int choiceMenu = 0;
std::cin >> choiceMenu;
while (std::cin.fail() || choiceMenu < 1 || choiceMenu > 5) {
    std::cout << "Invalid choice, try again: ";
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), delim);
    std::cin >> choiceMenu;
}
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), delim);
```

Возможна ситуация, когда число успешно прочитано, но выполнено условие `choiceMenu < 1 || choiceMenu > 5`. Вызов `ignore()` в данном случае, по идее, не должен создавать проблем, т.к. он всего лишь извлечёт оставшийся во входном потоке символ новой строки.

Также нужно иметь ввиду, что строку наподобие такой

```
2test
```

приведённый код считает корректным вводом. Переменной `choiceMenu` будет присвоено значение `2`, а последовательность символов `test` будет прочитана функцией `ignore()` после цикла.

---

Если воспользоваться [перенаправлением ввода](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0) так, чтобы входной поток читал данные из файла, а файл сделать пустым, то приведённый цикл ввода станет бесконечным.

Попытались считать число из пустого файла — ничего не вышло, установили флаги `failbit` и `eofbit`.
Очистили флаги ошибок, снова пытаемся считать число из пустого файла — ничего не вышло.
Снова очищаем флаги, снова пытаемся считать, и т.д.

А ещё в процессе считывания может быть установлен флаг `badbit`, сигнализирующий о наличии каких-то очень серьёзных проблем в работе потока.

Поэтому приведённый код, возможно, следует переписать даже так:

```
#include <limits>
#include <cstdlib>
...

auto delim = decltype(std::cin)::traits_type::to_int_type('\n');

int choiceMenu = 0;
std::cin >> choiceMenu;
while (std::cin.fail() || choiceMenu < 1 || choiceMenu > 5) {
    if (std::cin.bad() || std::cin.eof()) {
        std::cout << "fatal error" << std::endl;
        //Прерываем цикл. Если в функции main, то просто закончим работу.
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    std::cout << "Invalid choice, try again: ";
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), delim);
    std::cin >> choiceMenu;
}
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), delim);
```

[Ссылка на пример](https://ideone.com/5ni9hg).