# Как исправить ошибку в C++

Tags: c++

Учу C++. Сделал консольный калькулятор. Когда пишу много чисел и нажимаю enter появляется это:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда пишу строчные буквы тоже так. Почему так происходит? Вот код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{   
int a;
int b;
std::string c;

std::cout << "Input first number: ";
std::cin >> a;
std::cout << "Input second number: ";
std::cin >> b;
std::cout << "Choice symbol +,-,/,*: ";
std::cin >> c;

if (c == "+") {
     int d = a + b;
     std::cout << "Result: " << d << "\n";
}
else if (c == "-") {
     int d = a - b;
     std::cout << "Result: " << d << "\n";
}
else if (c == "/") {
     int d = a / b;
     std::cout << "Result: " << d << "\n";
}
else if (c == "*") {
     int d = a * b;
     std::cout << "Result: " << d << "\n";
}
else {
     std::cout << "Input symbol!!!";
}

std::string ret;

std::cout << "Return? y or n: ";
std::cin >> ret;

if (ret == "n") {
      
}
else {
     main();
}
```

}

Comment: После каждого ввода надо проверять результат - успех/неуспех. Если неуспех, надо пропускать строку с ошибочными данными на входе и восстанавливать нормальное состояние потока ввода.

Comment: При откладке говорится "Ваша программа вызвала нарушение доступа(ошибку сегментации)"

Comment: Вы `main` рекурсивно запускаете. Вот программа и падает.

Comment: Все понял, int хранит от -2 147 483 648 до 2 147 483 647 чисел и если число превышает 2 147 483 647 будет такая ошибка

Comment: Если произошёл сбой при вводе, то поток переходит в ошибочное состояние, и дальнейшие попытки ввода игнорируются. Например, здесь `std::cin >> ret;` переменной `ret` не будет присвоено новое значение, а значит не будет выполнено условие `if (ret == "n")`, следовательно, функция `main` будет неограниченно вызывать саму себя. Посмотрите некоторые идеи, как можно восстановить поток [в этом вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1271404). P.S. Функция `main` особенная — вы не должны вызывать её самостоятельно, т.к. это вызывает неопределённое поведение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно так

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>



int a, b;
std::string c, ret = "n";

void Calk() {
    for(;;) {
        
            std::cout << "Input first number: " << "\n";
            std::cin >> a;
            std::cout << "Input second number: " << "\n";
            std::cin >> b;
            std::cout << "Choice symbol +,-,/,*: " << "\n";
            std::cin >> c;
        
            if (c == "+") {
                int d = a + b;
                std::cout << "Result +: " << d << "\n";

                std::cout << "Return? y or n: " << "\n";
                std::cin >> ret;
                if (ret == "n") {
                    break;
                }
                
            }
            else if (c == "-") {
                int d = a - b;
                std::cout << "Result -: " << d << "\n";

                std::cout << "Return? y or n: " << "\n";
                std::cin >> ret;
                if (ret == "n") {
                    break;
                }
            }
            else if (c == "/") {
                int d = a / b;
                std::cout << "Result /: " << d << "\n";

                std::cout << "Return? y or n: " << "\n";
                std::cin >> ret;
                if (ret == "n") {
                    break;
                }
            }
            else if (c == "*") {
                int d = a * b;
                std::cout << "Result *: " << d << "\n";

                std::cout << "Return? y or n: " << "\n";
                std::cin >> ret;
                if (ret == "n") {
                    break;
                }
            }
            else {
                std::cout << "Input symbol!!!";

                std::cout << "Return? y or n: " << "\n";
                std::cin >> ret;
                if (ret == "n") {
                    break;
                }
            }
    }

}

int main()
{   
  
    Calk();
    

}
```

Код можно сократить но пока так вам будет более понятно.
А то что вы делаете c main это немного не обычно :)

https://godbolt.org/z/KEx1jv74q

Comment: Спасибо вам, понял :)

Answer (score 1):

`main()` это точка входа в программу, её не нужно рекурсивно вызывать. То что вы хотите добавте ваш код в цилк `do while`: